# how to run Github Actions Jobs in parallel using matrix?

Tags: github-actions

I've really struggled here doing this for the first time and having no background in development.
We have an action that checks the status of several services running on different envs (**DEV, TEST, PROD**) and sends notifications to Microsoft Teams Channel.
At the moment there is a dedicated action for each env and the goal is to combine them in one.
the action itself:

```
name: Services Health Check
    
    on:
      workflow_dispatch:
      schedule:
        - cron:  '*/30 * * * *'
    
    
    env:
      DEV: https://app.dev.contoso.com
      TEST: https://app.test.contoso.com
      PROD: https://app.contoso.com
    
      TEAMS_TOKEN_DEV: ${{ secrets.HEALTH_CHECK_TEAMS_WEB_HOOK_URL_DEV }}
      TEAMS_TOKEN_TEST: ${{ secrets.HEALTH_CHECK_TEAMS_WEB_HOOK_URL_TEST }}
      TEAMS_TOKEN_PROD: ${{ secrets.HEALTH_CHECK_TEAMS_WEB_HOOK_URL_PROD }}
    
    jobs:

#here I want to create a matrix as a JSON array to look like this, but Im not sure if I do it right (I am also not sure if I correctly escape the characters and which one should I escape):  
#[  
# { dev : https://app.dev.contoso.com,  webhook : ${{ secrets.WEB_HOOK_URL_DEV }}  },  
# {test : https://app.test.contoso.com, webhook : ${{ secrets.WEB_HOOK_URL_TEST }} },  
# {prod : https://app.contoso.com,      webhook : ${{ secrets.WEB_HOOK_URL_TEST }} }  
#]

      env-matrix:
        name: Setup ENV Matrix 
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        outputs:
          matrix: ${{ steps.matrix.outputs.env }}
        steps:
          - id: matrix-env
            run: |
              echo '::set-output name=env::[\{\"env\"\:\"$DEV\", \"webhook\"\:\"$TEAMS_TOKEN_DEV\"\}, \{\"env\"\:\"$DEMO\", \"webhook\"\:\"$TEAMS_TOKEN_DEMO\"\}, \{\"env\"\:\"$TEST\", \"webhook\"\:\"$TEAMS_TOKEN_TEST\"\}, \{\"env\"\:\"$POC\", \"webhook\"\:\"$TEAMS_TOKEN_POC\"\}, \{\"env\"\:\"$PRE\", \"webhook\"\:\"$TEAMS_TOKEN_PRE\"\}, \{\"env\"\:\"$PROD\", \"webhook\"\:\"$TEAMS_TOKEN_PROD\"\}]'
    
#and the healthcheck job itself

      healthcheck:
        needs: env-matrix
        name: Health Check
        runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
        strategy:
          matrix:
            value: ${{ fromJson(needs.env-matrix.outputs.matrix-env)}}
        steps:
          - name: service1
            uses: repo/action
            continue-on-error: true
            with:
              url: '${{ matrix.value.env }}/service1/q/health/ready'
              teamsWebHookURL: '${{ matrix.value.webhook }}'
    
          - name: service2
            uses: repo/action
            continue-on-error: true
            with:
              url: '${{ matrix.value.env }}/service2/q/health/ready'
              teamsWebHookURL: '${{ matrix.value.webhook }}'
```

so the job must run on DEV with TEAMS_TOKEN_DEV, on TEST with TEAMS_TOKEN_TEST, but I don't know the way to access an array item, so the steps are incorrect.
Any help will be appreciated. If you know a simpler solution pls share.
Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of rewriting your workflow is to define the name of the secrets in the matrix and then using Array notation to fetch the actual value of the secrets. Below is a way of doing this and it is not a clone of your workflow. But this should give you an idea.

```yaml
name: Services Health Check

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  healthcheck:
    name: Health Check
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    strategy:
      matrix:
        environment: [dev, test, prod]
        include:
          - environment: dev
            url: https://app.dev.contoso.com
            webhook: HEALTH_CHECK_TEAMS_WEB_HOOK_URL_DEV
          - environment: test
            url: https://app.test.contoso.com
            webhook: HEALTH_CHECK_TEAMS_WEB_HOOK_URL_TEST
          - environment: prod
            url: https://app.prod.contoso.com
            webhook: HEALTH_CHECK_TEAMS_WEB_HOOK_URL_PROD
    steps:
      - name: test_1
        run: |
          echo ${{ format('{0}{1}', matrix.url, '/service1/q/health/ready') }}
          echo ${{secrets[matrix.webhook]}}
      - name: test_2
        run: |
          echo ${{ format('{0}{1}', matrix.url, '/service2/q/health/ready') }}
          echo ${{secrets[matrix.webhook]}}
```

Comment: oh my god, man, thank you so much. it definitely should help.